# Array<int ***[10]>v, How to get the total number of * and 10 in [10] for C + + template?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, templates

```
using view_type1 = Kokkos::View<double ****>;
using view_type2 = Kokkos::View<double ***[3][1]>;
```

The Kokkos code! I want to know How to get the total number of * and 10 in [10] for  C + + template?

Comment: [Don't be a three star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: you want some `get_number_of_stars<double***> == 3;` ?

Comment: @NathanOliver this guy is transcending 3, going to the moon with 4.

Comment: I think you can find all you need in `<type_traits>`, though its not clear what you need exactly